# Magnolia CMS 5.4 (activation)

Tags: magnolia

I have a problem with making changes to my css file (Hotfix resource, Publish). If I want to publish changes in my style.css it gives me an error:

```
2015-07-29 09:49:45,592 ERROR info.magnolia.module.activation.ExchangeTask      : Failed to deactivate content.
info.magnolia.cms.exchange.ExchangeException: Not able to send the activation request [http:// localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation]: http:// localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.BaseSyndicatorImpl.activate(BaseSyndicatorImpl.java:443)
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.SimpleSyndicator$2.runTask(SimpleSyndicator.java:132)
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.ExchangeTask.run(ExchangeTask.java:75)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:// localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1889)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1883)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1456)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:739)
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.BaseSyndicatorImpl.activate(BaseSyndicatorImpl.java:428)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:// localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1835)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2942)
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.BaseSyndicatorImpl.transportActivatedData(BaseSyndicatorImpl.java:482)
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.BaseSyndicatorImpl.activate(BaseSyndicatorImpl.java:407)
    ... 4 more
2015-07-29 09:49:45,596 ERROR info.magnolia.module.activation.SimpleSyndicator  : Not able to send the activation request [http:// localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation]: http:// localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation
info.magnolia.cms.exchange.ExchangeException: Not able to send the activation request [http:// localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation]: http:// localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.BaseSyndicatorImpl.activate(BaseSyndicatorImpl.java:443)
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.SimpleSyndicator$2.runTask(SimpleSyndicator.java:132)
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.ExchangeTask.run(ExchangeTask.java:75)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:// localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1889)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1883)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1456)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:739)
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.BaseSyndicatorImpl.activate(BaseSyndicatorImpl.java:428)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:// localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1835)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2942)
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.BaseSyndicatorImpl.transportActivatedData(BaseSyndicatorImpl.java:482)
    at info.magnolia.module.activation.BaseSyndicatorImpl.activate(BaseSyndicatorImpl.java:407)
    ... 4 more
```

I do not know what is this error and how to fix it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It is the correct output http://pastebin.com/Yxr57ZbK

Comment: Ah, ok. Is your public instance running? When you put http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/admincentral into your browser, do you see Magnolia login form?

Comment: No i don't see login,
but i use this http://localhost:8080/app-project-webapp/.magnolia/admincentral and i see login.

Comment: OK, then you probably have just one - development - instance, and no public instance, right?

Comment: How do I check if I have the public instance?
So i think, now i have an instance of development.

Comment: Well, have you installed/deployed one? ;-) So the problem is, that you have no public instance (because you are probably just developing), so no need to publish (activate) your changes. It would be also good to deactivate the subscriber (set the `active` property to `false`), otherwise you will get errors when deleting nodes in your workspaces (because the delete command tries to deactivate the content first, but there is no public instance).

Comment: Now there is no error, writes "Application successful", but the changes made in the css file (not visible in magnolia) :/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you have misconfigured the subscriber: there is few times `http:// localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation` in the stacktrace - with a space between `http://` and `localhost:8080...`. Check the subscriber configuration, remove the space, and let us know. ;-)

Comment: It was only for the purpose of pasting code.
Look pastebin link.